# How can I get a value from a map if I have the key?

Tags: java, dictionary, bufferedreader

For reference, I am creating a Huffman tree for an assignment in school. I have created the tree, and stored values in a map using this format:

```
map.put((char,string));
```

char: is derived by reading one character at a time from a buffered reader 
string: is the "binary" code assigned to that character based on its tree placement

Now I want to produce a String of "binary" that represents my initial input from the buffered reader. How do I do this? This is what I've tried:

```
String binary = "";
int q;    
while ((q = buffer.read()) != -1) {
  char key = (char)q;
  char value = (char)key.get();
  binary += value;
}
System.out.println(binary);
```

Comment: What is the declaration of the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shouldn't it just be value = map.get(key)  ?

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was missing something simple. I should really sleep at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do if I want to get all the keys and values from a map:

```
Set <generics> mySet = myMap.keySet(); // takes all the keys to a set
Iterator itr = mySet.iterator(); // setting iterator to the set containing the keys

//iterate through the set of keys

while (itr.hasNext()){

              keys = itr.next(); //get the keys from the set
              values = myMap.get (keys); //get the values from the map

}//while (itr.hasNext())
```